# how do you use $.parseJSON in jQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using this function to test the validity of JSON objects:

```
function is_JSON( test ) {
    try { var c = $.parseJSON( test );
    } catch (e) { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

You can see it work great here, with jQuery 1.8.3 ...

http://jsfiddle.net/xZYVY/

... but if you switch to jQuery 1.9.1, this doesn't work!

http://jsfiddle.net/xZYVY/1/

What am I missing? Is there a better way to test for valid JSON?

Comment: Maybe because it's not valid JSON, it's an array? [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZYVY/2/) with valid JSON works just fine!

Comment: A quick way to check on such things is to go the jQuery download page and look for the code in the old and new uncompressed versions. For some things that can be tricky, but "parseJSON" is one of the more obvious ones, and the differences in this case are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
var test = ['thing1','thing2','thing3'];
```

Creates an array instead of a string containing a valid JSON expression. The reason why it *seemed to work* with 1.8.3 is because back then [`parseJSON`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/core.js#L490) looked like this:

```
function( data ) {
if ( !data || typeof data !== "string") {
        return null;
    }
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, if you pass an array as the first argument, it will return `null`; it doesn't throw an exception.

Your function then returns `true`:

```
parseJSON: function is_JSON( test ) {
    try { var c = $.parseJSON( test );
    } catch (e) { return false; }
    // c === null
    return true;
}
```

Since 1.9, this is what [`parseJSON`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/core.js#L490) looks like:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    if ( data === null ) {
        return data;
    }
    if ( data === null ) {
        return data;
    }
    // etc.
```

And `window.JSON.parse()` will throw an exception if the passed parameter is not a valid JSON expression.

A valid expression would be this:

```
'["thing1","thing2","thing3"]'
```

To test:

```
> JSON.parse('["thing1","thing2","thing3"]')
["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"]
```

Comment: Is it possible that we set jQuery object so the json.parse() in version 1.9+ returns null (same as previous versions)?

Answer (score 1):

Your "test" variable is simply not a valid JSON string; it's a JavaScript array.

[Here is a fixed version where the value is a JSON string.](http://jsfiddle.net/KD2pq/)

```
 var test = '["thing1","thing2","thing3"]';
```

Now, it's interesting that 1.8.3 doesn't act that way, I'll admit. Time for research ...

OK, prior to 1.9, the `$.parseJSON()` code would quickly return `null` for non-string argument values.  Now, it just as quickly defers to the native `JSON.parse()` if available, and since that throws an error on non-string, non-null arguments, you get the exception now.

Comment: I converted it into a JSON string, and it still returned no. I think it is due to how he is reporting it as false by catching an exception. I don't think $.parseJSON is throwing an exception maybe?

Comment: How do you convert an array to JSON string in JS (please say JSON.stringify) ?

Comment: @crush it works when it's a proper JSON string; see the linked update to the original fiddle.

Comment: JSON.parse also fails, so 1.8 is probably using something else?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, the `.parseJSON()` function was changed between 1.8 and 1.9 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the opposite of what you say: in jQuery/1.8 it wasn't working as you expect because an invalid JSON string makes `$.parseJSON()` return `null`. However, in jQuery/1.9 it does throw an exception.

As per the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

> Passing in a malformed JSON string *may* result in an exception being thrown

So you cannot rely on that behaviour. You need to test the return value as well.