# JSON.parse error protection

Tags: jquery, json

My script gets some stringified json data from cookie.

```
var cookie = $.cookie('someKey');
if (typeof(cookie) == 'string') {
    var fromCookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
}
```

Data comes from user via cookie, so I want to be sure that it is json.
If it is not json, script stops with error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object
var fromCookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
```

How to check data and get *false* to **fromCokie** instead of getting error

Comment: See this question a few questions below this one, which shows a try/catch method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093419/how-do-you-use-parsejson-in-jquery-1-9-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the string to parse is not valid JSON, a SyntaxError exception is
>   thrown.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

You should surround it in a try/catch block, to catch the exception:

```
var cookie = $.cookie('someKey');
if (typeof(cookie) == 'string') {

    var fromCookie = false;

    try {
        fromCookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
    } catch (e) {
        fromCookie = false;
    }
}
```

You don't really need to test if the cookie is a string here, but I left it in case you had some other code to execute as well.

Answer (score 6):

You want a `try catch` block:

```
var fromCookie;
try {
    fromCookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
} catch (e) {
    fromCookie = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to write a full JSON parser, I suggest to use `try-catch`.